# FIR filter | how can I change the axis to unnormalized?

Tags: filter-design

I don't understand why my output graphs and not showing the real frequencies, tried to change it in a number of ways with no luck. so far I'm stuck.

This is what I have done so far while implementing a LowPassFilter using the frequency sampling method:

```
M=63 
Wp=0.25*pi                           %Number of samples/passband cutoff 
                                     %frequency. 
m=0:(M+1)/2
Wm=3*Wp*m./(M+1)                     %sampling points and the stopband 
                                     %cutoff frequency
mtr=floor(Wp*(M+1)/(2*pi))+2
Ad=[Wm<=Wp]
Ad(mtr)=0.38
fs=4*Wp                              %sample frequency

Hd=Ad.*exp(-j*0.5*M*Wm)              %frequency sampling vector. 
Hd=[Hd conj(fliplr(Hd(2:(M+1)/2)))]  %fliplr(A) returns A with its 
                                     %columns flipped in the left-right 
                                     %direction. 

h=real(ifft(Hd)); %h(n)=IDFT(H(k))
w=linspace(0,pi,1000);               %get 1000 row vectors between 0 and pi
H=freqz(h,[1],w);                    %the amplitude/frequency diagram of the filter. 
                                     %Frequency response of digital filter.
figure(1)
plot(w/pi,20*log10(abs(H)));         %parameters are respectively the 
                                     %normalized frequency and 
                                     %amplitude. 
xlabel('Normalized frequency');
ylabel('Gain/dB');
title('LowPass Filter - Gain response');
axis([0 1 -50 2]);

f1=100;                             %frequencies of sine input signals.
f2=300;
f3=700;
figure(2)
subplot(211)
                 
T=1/fs;                             % Sampling period       
L=200000;                           % Length of signal (time duration)
t=(0:L-1)*T;                        % Time vector
f = fs/2*linspace(0,1,L/2+1);       % single-sided positive frequency

s=sin(2*pi*f1*t)+sin(2*pi*f2*t)+sin(2*pi*f3*t); %input signal definition
plot(t,s);                                      %diagmram plot before 
                                                %filtering 
xlabel('time [Sec]');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Time domain diagram before filtering');
axis([0 200 -3 3]);
subplot(212)

n = 2^nextpow2(L);
Fs=fft(s)/L;
AFs=abs(Fs/n);            %transformation to frequency domain.
plot(f,AFs(1:L/2+1));     %frequency Domain diagram plot before filtering.
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]'); 
ylabel('Amplitude'); 
title('Frequency Domain diagram before filtering')
```

The output so far:

- I'm trying to make the x axis present the original frequencies.

[image: LowPassFilter Gain Response]

And again, the graph "Frequency Domain diagram before filtering", is not presenting the original frequencies:
[image: Frequency Domain diagram before filtering]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You set you sample rate `fs` to 3.14 Hz (pi) but than you have sine waves at much higher frequencies so you primarily aliasing. Your your axis is correct, it goes from 0 pit $\pi/2$ Hz

Comment: you're, I've overlooked it somehow

Answer (score 1):

To change to frequencies in units of Hz for the filter multiply the frequency axis by half the sampling rate, as below where fs is the sampling rate:

```
plot(w/pi * fs/2,20*log10(abs(H)));
```

For your lower plot you are not sampling high enough such that the desired frequencies are in the first Nyquist zone. The frequencies desired are 100, 300 and 700 Hz but the sampling rate is given as $\pi$ (which would therefore more generally be the normalized radian frequency).  Either provide the actual sampling rate in Hz at a rate sufficiently high such that 700 Hz is in the first Nyquist zone ($fs >> 1400$ Hz), or describe the frequency components in $s$ as normalized frequencies by dividing by the actual sampling rate.  For example if the sampling rate was 2 KHz, then f1 would be $700/2000 = 0.35$ cycles/sample and the frequency axis would be adjusted just as done above with the filter by multiplying by half the sampling rate.

Comment: got it now it works, thank you!